# webdriver.Chrome() location, using Jupyter Notebook, mac OS Ventura 13.5.1

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, macos-ventura

I´m using a Macbook Air M2 chip and I´m getting the following error: `[Errno 86] Bad CPU type in executable.`

My code is the following:

```
pip install selenium
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

I downloaded the following `chromedriver` version: https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/116.0.5845.96/mac-arm64/chromedriver-mac-arm64.zip, my Chrome version is `116.0.5845.110`.

The location of my script is in `/Users/myname/anaconda3/bin`, I copied the `chromedriver.exe` from Downloads to the location of my script and I´m having that error.

Am I missing something ? Hope the community can help.

I´ve tried moving the `chromedriver.exe` in different locations I tried defining the path as another variable but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Hi everyone who watched this post. I came up with a solution. I can confirm that this is working:

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time


driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))